WordPress Strip plugin has been deactivated and subscription order goes Pending payment
We're experiencing an issue with the Stripe plugin in WordPress, which was deactivated, causing all subscription orders to be stuck in a pending payment state.
Is there a way to retry these payments?
In the order details, we're only seeing a note that says:

